# Unity 2D Tap to shoot at mouse position on android device

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, input, raycasting

Hello everyone i am really stuck at the moment and would appreciate any help if possible. I have my game where i move the player up and down with 2 buttons on the bottom left of screenshot.

I also have a button over the entire screen for tap to shoot and this moves the weapon to my finger position where i have tapped and it shoots towards that position using mouse.position.

Now the problem is when i am on my android device and i am moving up and down but when i also tap to shoot the gun it moves towards my up and down buttons and this is not what i want.

i want to be able to move with my finger and also shoot towards the second finger.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my Tap to shoot button code!

```
public void ShootButton()
{
 timer = 0;
 Face = true;
 //if finger presses Shootbutton
 //then activate this

 Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - 
 transform.position; 
 // subtracting the position of the player from the mouse position.
 difference.Normalize(); //normalizing the vector meaning all the sum of the 
 vector will be = to 1.

 float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;//find 
 the angle in degree.

 WeaponTrans.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ + 
 rotationOffset);
 if (reloading == false)
 {
     if (fireRate == 0)
     {
         {
             Shoot();
         }
     }
     else
     {
         if (Time.time > timeToFire)
         {
             timeToFire = Time.time + 1 / fireRate;
             Shoot();
         }
     }
 }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m not sure what you exactly meant. But I guess you mean on a touchscreen.
And your weapon jumps around once you click any of the up & down buttons.
1) use Input.Touch instead of Input.mousePosition
2) use a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach(Touch t in Input.Touches)
 {
   //now you have different posibilities:
   //one of them could be 
   if(t.position is inside of the button)
   {
     //do not use it for detecting direction
   }
   else
   {
     //the touch position is not inside a button => execute shoot code
   }
 }
```

also, you said you have a button over the entire sceen to detect touches: That´s bad practise you can use touch phases like this:

```
switch(touch.phase)
{
  case Touchphase.Began:
  //code executed when the finger touches the screen
  break;
  case Touchphase.Ended:
  //code executed when the finger leaves the screen
  break;
}
```

I guess that takes to long to explain but there are tons of good videos out there. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrCUO46jcxk) one might explain it good.

If you have more questions feel free to comment and ask on specific. I might able to answer more specific then